# Magento 2.3.2 minicart issue

Tags: cart, magento2.3, mini-cart, magento2-migration-tool

Recently we upgraded Data from `Magento 1.9.4` version in to `Magento 2.3.2` [we did data migration].

After Data migration, we are facing issue with minicart section. if we click on minicart button it is redirecting to `checkout/cart` page, instead of showing the minicart items,`view/edit` cart button, proceed to checkout etc.

I did `setup:upgrade`, `compile`, `content-deploy`, `reindex`, `cache clean`, `cache flush`. Got some information from google, create custom module and over ride cart action. But i am not getting full clarity what i need to do .

There is no issue with order place. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This issue is in Luma theme ?

Comment: yes, this issue in luma theme. @HassanAliShahzad

Comment: Any js error you see in console?

Comment: yes @ArifAhmad, after click on minicart icon, console i am seeing "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1". But don't know how to fix this.

Comment: This "JQMIGRATE" doesn't look like an error. It's hard to tell what is the reason. It needs to be debugged to understand. If you can share a public URL then someone might look into it. 
Some tips: Check if the page is fully loaded. If not fully loaded and you click on it it will take to cart page as JS is not yet triggered. Check in network if all scripts are loaded or you are getting some errors or something keeps loading. Look for minicart.js in Network and make sure it is loaded and not empty